# Abelian normal subgroup

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group with an abelian normal subgroup $N$. Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ and suppose that $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$ for some prime $p$.

> Question: if $p$ divides $|N|$, then $P$ is normal in $N$.

I just need to show that $P\leq N$ but I can't seem to see why that is the case. I know that since p divides $|N|$, we have that $N$ contains a subgroup of order $p$ ($N$ is a finite supersolvable group)

Comment: consider dihedral group of order 12. rotation group is normal, a subgroup of order 2, with any reflection satisfies your conditions, but it is not normal in $N$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something is missing here, as this is incorrect as stated.  Maybe there's a typo.

For instance, take $G = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} / 4 \mathbb{Z}$ with $N = \mathbb{Z} / 2\mathbb{Z}$ and $H = \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$.  Then if you take $p = 2$, $P = \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ which clearly isn't a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z}$.